# How to use flat colors to determine how a scene looks? I want no shadows just colored shapes

Tags: materials, light, color

Is it possible for blender to just use colors to determine how a scene looks? I want no shadows, just the colors, like in after effects but 3D.

I´m trying to replicate the following:

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful y you could add some image as an example

Comment: Could you share an illustration of the specific look you are after?

Comment: Sorry for that, I added the picture

Answer (score 1):

Basically, toon shaders for all the gears. Some depth of field and the most important camera setting: Orthographic. Then my sun casts no shadows. Add vignette in Compositing and that's pretty much it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or emission shaders for 2.8+

Comment: Very late, but I tried this to see if this worked better than my fix, but setting camera to orthographic messes up my camera movement completly, so it isn´t much use

Comment: Well, ortho was just to make sure you don't use perspective. You'd need your gears to have nearly zero thickness to makem them appear 2D.